# CentOS 6 Include Gateway for Static IP Address

Tags: centos, networking, ip, gateway

I've just set up a static IP Address for my CentOS Machine using the following settings in
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
#eth0 Config 
#IPv4 

DEVICE="eth0" 
NM_CONTROLLED="yes" 
ONBOOT=yes 
HWADDR=*get from ifconfig* 
TYPE=Ethernet 
BOOTPROTO=static 
NAME="System eth0" 
IPADDR=10.0.0.66 
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.0.0.2
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

That's all working but when I reboot the machine I can't connect to the network and I see it's because it doesn't have the gateway which is 10.0.0.2

I tried to add it as well with
/etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes 
NETWORKING_IPV6=no 
HOSTNAME=centos66
```

When I reboot I see that the hostname is now centos66 but it still doesn't have the gateway?

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

*UPDATE*

The DNS had to be added which fixed the issues, I'll leave this here for whoever might be helped by it

Comment: why don't you put GATEWAY=10.0.0.2 in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 ?

Comment: I'll try that and see if it works

Comment: It seems to get me one step closer I think

Comment: Is your resolv.conf ok? You can put also DNS in your config. E.g DNS1=x.x.x.x DNS2=xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: Oh wow the DNS fixed it, thanks so much taliezin, could you post your solution as an answer so I can choose it as the right one?

Comment: It is ok. You can post your changes as an answer and you can accept it. It was just a good catch from me...

Comment: It was really clever for you to know I didn't do DNS settings because I'm too stupid